# Ruby conditional, array and iterating

Tags: ruby, arrays, conditional-statements

Well, I have a problem in Ruby about array and iterating. I'm a noob.
Let's get to the point. Here's the problem :

1. I have an array, let's say the name is myary = []
2. myary contains 25 integer data from index 1 - 25, those are integer 1 - 25. index 0 is nil.
3. I have a variable, let's say the name is myvar( I don't know the value of this variable).

Then I have this code

```
puts "I can do that"
```

Now here goes the task : 
puts "I can do that" will be executed only if myvar's value is not 1,2,3 and so on until 25. 
The question is how do I check the value of myvar ? And also how to give the order to execute puts "I can do that" if the value of myvar is not between 1 and 25. I might try it like this :

```
puts "I can do that" if myvar != 1 || myvar != 2 || myvar != 3  # and so on until myvar != 25
```

But I believe that is ridiculous way, if I need to check until 100 then I will be damned.
Perhaps there an elegant way to do this. And perhaps someone can help a noob like me.

I hope I explain it clearly because I myself is a little confused with this damn task. 
Thank you very much all.

EDIT : Ahh umm sorry for not mention it earlier I just figure out something that bothered me, I notice that if myvar is a float between 1 - 25 it should not execute the code "I can do that".
Now this drive me more crazy. But thanks for every answer here, though I try that it still print out "I can do that" when the value of myvar is a float i.e 1.5, 2.5 and so on.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In your example code, you don't mention `myary` at all. What does the array have to do with checking the value of `myvar`?

Comment: Now that is I just don't know what to do with myary, so I do that ridiculous or conditional. I know I should do something with the array. but I'm to dumb to know it, that's why I need help.

Comment: @LuminaChen: As you are asking the question, you *cannot* be too dumb :-) However that does not spare you from deciding what you *want*. All of the answers solve a problem that looks *remotly* like yours. However, as long as we do not understand *exactly* what you want we have a hard time providing it. Especially the fragment "index 0 is nil" left me confused. What shall happen if `myvar == nil`? Or to put this the other way round: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Patru Sorry because I'm to dumb, I have said "I'm a noob" and Ihave state this too "I hope I explain it clearly because I myself is a little confused with this damn task" Therefore again I'm sorry if I'm not be clear, if myvar == nil it should not execute the code, the reason I still no got the best answer is like I have edited in my question, when myvar is a float like 1.5, 2.5 the code still executed, puts "I can do that". 
My goal : Can someone help me with how to check myvar value with an elegant code, if myvar has the same value with one of index(in this case index 1 - 25) in myary..

Comment: then it should not execute the code. The parameter is the value of index 1 - 25 in myary array, and that is absoulute, not a plain 1..25, but the value inside the array index 1 - 25(which in this case contain 1 - 25 integer data) and also index 0 is nil. I know that is a coincidence perhaps with plain 1..25, Well I admit I'm not good at explain a problem, so again I'm very sorry for my dumbness. As I looked all of answer still print "I can do that" if myvar value is a float like 1.5, 2.5, and so on until 24.5, perhaps I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this

```
puts "I can do that" unless myary.include?(myvar)
```

Comment: That is certainly close, but it implicitly assumes that `myvar` and `myary` are related (which is not stated explicitly). It also neglects the (strange) condition that `myary[0]` should be `nil` (the OP explicitly stated this). However the task at hand should be possibly with just `puts "I can do that" unless (1..25).to_a.include? myvar` which does not even look at `myary`. Note that this does not print for `myvar=24.5` which is different from the pure range solution of @Max.

Comment: Ups sorry did not notice this, It was very late of night, and maybe I'm to sleepy, sorry..

Comment: Ups sorry did not notice this, It was very late of night, and maybe I'm to sleepy, sorry..

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `myvar` to a range:

```
puts "I can do that" unless (1..25) === myvar
```

Comment: I would prefer `(1..25).include? myvar`

Answer (score 0):

As you do not seem to notice it in a comment I will turn it into an answer and explain some more. You could do the following:

```
myary = (1..25).to_a
puts "I can do that" unless myary.include? myvar
```

The first line will turn the range `1..25` into an array with the elements from 1 to 25 at indices 0 to 24, this avoids having `nil` in the array which was not helpful in the first place. I will modify the code a little to see more easily if it does what you want:

```
myary = (1..25).to_a
[0, 1, 2, 10, 10.5, 20, 24.5, 25, 26, nil].each do |myvar|
  puts "I can do that (#{myvar})" unless myary.include? myvar
end
```

This yields

```
I can do that (0)
I can do that (10.5)
I can do that (24.5)
I can do that (26)
I can do that ()
 => [0, 1, 2, 10, 10.5, 20, 24.5, 25, 26]
```

which corresponds to my understanding of what you seem to want (even if it seems to contradict your last sentence which seems to contradict whatever you have written before :-).

Please feel free to add to your question if you should desire otherwise.

If you *really* do not want the line to print for a float in the range from `(1..25)` then an array would be just the wrong data structure and you should use the range as outlined earlier. Using the same test values as before:

```
[0, 1, 2, 10, 10.5, 20, 24.5, 25, 26].each do |myvar|
  puts "I can do that (#{myvar})" unless (1..25).include? myvar
end
```

and you end up with

I can do that (0)
   I can do that (26)

It is up to you which version is more to your likings.

Comment: Hi patru apparently I'm to sleepy last night and didn't notice your answer in comment below, I'm very sorry. And also I confused with my logic, yes it should print up the code, if myvar value is a float. And if myvar nil the code should executed too. Sorry I have confused you with my silly question. But thanks you're great. Only I notice when myvar is nil it's not executed the code "I can do that". How can I make it print out "I can do that" if myvar value is nil? Thanks Patru :) 
Well sorry for my "great" english.
That's my last problem.

Comment: @LuminaChen: As far as I can tell the first code block in this answer should do what you wanted. I have added `nil` as an example in the second block and it prints out the text (even if it does not show `nil` in parentheses, but that would be a different problem). If you have more or different requirements you should add a code block as the second one to your answer and supplement it with your expected answer. Code is very expressive and it can tell programmers a lot more than a lot of words (as most of us have sorely learnt). StackOverflow is the right place to ask your questions with code.

Comment: Umm but the code is valid because it indicates that `myary` contains ` 1 - 25 from index 0 - 24. And in my case index 0 is equal to `nil`. Actually here's the task I have from my senior, sorry not post it earlier :
`myary = [] `
`myary[0] = nil `
`for i in 1..25 `
  ` myary[i] = 0 + i `  
So that's why index 0 is explicitly equal to `nil`. 
And when I use your `puts "I can do that" unless myary.include? myvar` It's not print `I can do that` if `myvar = nil` 
Or I missed something again? Sorry for all this problem patru :(

Comment: @LuminaChen: Code looks messy in comments if it is more than a single line, that's why I suggested you edit the question. If you *have* to use `myary` as you defined it then you would probably have to use `myary.index(myvar)` to check an element, but that will return `nil` if `myvar` cannot be found and you would have to check for this explicitly. That will make it `puts "I can do that" if myary.index(myvar).nil? || myary.index(myvar) < 1` which is ugly as it relies on `nil` being the first element, but it should do. However you might just as well check for `nil` explicitly. Strange exercise.

Comment: hello patru.  
`puts "I can do that" if myary.index(myvar).nil? || myary.index(myvar)`  
Yes this really work nice. Thank you very much patru. Yeah this strange exercise come from logic class, and I believe the people there also strange. Anyway thanks patru I appreciate it very much.